# Moving the cursor to a specified position as soon as it touches right edge of screen using autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have written code to change mouse position when it touches the left edge of screen

```
sysget, var_, monitorworkarea
gui, color, 0x000000
gui, +alwaysontop +toolwindow -caption
gui, show, w1 h%var_bottom% x0 y0, left_win
winset, transparent, 1, left_win

onmessage(0x200, "edge")
return

edge()
 {
   static countdown := 0
   if (countdown = 0)
    {
      settimer, check, -100
      countdown := 1
    }
   return
   
   check:
    {
      mousegetpos, , , win
      wingettitle, title, ahk_id %win%
      if (title = "left_win")
       {
         MouseMove, 960, 300, 0
       }
      countdown := 0
    }
   return
 }
```

but it doesn't work if I replace left with right for right edge of screen How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, check, -100
return

check(){
    If edge("left")
    {
        MouseMove, 960, 300, 0
        Send #x
    }
    else if edge("right")
    {
        MouseMove, 960, 300, 0
        Run Notepad
    }

    ; ...

    SetTimer, check, -100
}

edge(pos){
    SysGet, VirtualWidth, 78
    SysGet, VirtualHeight, 79
    T := 10 
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, mX, mY
    left := (mX < T)
    top := (mY < T)
    right := (mX > VirtualWidth - T)
    bottom := (mY > VirtualHeight - T)
    If (pos = "left")
        return left
    else if (pos = "top")
        return top
    else if (pos = "right")
        return right
    else if (pos = "bottom")
        return bottom
}
```